# Automated Install Fails due to CRC on /dev/sda

Tags: centos, partition, system-installation, kickstart

I'm running an X8STI-3F with an onboard LSI 1063E SAS controller running in IT mode.

I'm trying to get an automated install going on it and I keep getting

```
ddf1: physical drives with CRC AE516B03, expected FFFFFFFF on /dev/sda
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sda!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sda`
```

I've `dd`'ed out `/dev/sda` and continue to get the error.

```
[anaconda root@TPC-E2-11 ~]# dmraid -r
no raid disks
[anaconda root@TPC-E2-11 ~]# dmraid -l
asr     : Adaptec HostRAID ASR (0,1,10)
ddf1    : SNIA DDF1 (0,1,4,5,linear)
hpt37x  : Highpoint HPT37X (S,0,1,10,01)
hpt45x  : Highpoint HPT45X (S,0,1,10)
isw     : Intel Software RAID (0,1,5,01)
jmicron : JMicron ATARAID (S,0,1)
lsi     : LSI Logic MegaRAID (0,1,10)
nvidia  : NVidia RAID (S,0,1,10,5)
pdc     : Promise FastTrack (S,0,1,10)
sil     : Silicon Image(tm) Medley(tm) (0,1,10)
via     : VIA Software RAID (S,0,1,10)
dos     : DOS partitions on SW RAIDs

[anaconda root@TPC-E2-11 ~]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Aug 29 18:32 dm-name-live-base -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Aug 29 18:32 dm-name-live-rw -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Aug 29 19:07 scsi-35000cca00f08c5f0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Aug 29 18:46 scsi-35000cca00f08c5f0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Aug 29 19:07 wwn-0x5000cca00f08c5f0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Aug 29 18:46 wwn-0x5000cca00f08c5f0-part1 -> ../../sda1

[anaconda root@TPC-E2-11 ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 558.9G  0 disk
ââsda1        8:1    0   100M  0 part
loop0         7:0    0 278.8M  1 loop
loop1         7:1    0     2G  1 loop
ââlive-rw   253:0    0     2G  0 dm   /
ââlive-base 253:1    0     2G  1 dm
loop2         7:2    0   512M  0 loop
ââlive-rw   253:0    0     2G  0 dm   /

[anaconda root@TPC-E2-11 ~]# dmesg | grep ddf
[  182.059331] type=1400 audit(1409336387.072:42): avc:  denied  { add_name } for  pid=1563 comm="dmraid" name="dmraid.ddf1" scontext=system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:root_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

What does the error mean?

How do I prevent it from showing up in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dmraid -r -E /dev/sda
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
#mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda
```

It is also possible to do this automatically by editing the Kickstart file to use clearpart option, see: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-options.html

Comment: I'm already using clearpart and there are no partitions on /dev/sda at the time of creation.